# Laravel blades performance

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the laravel blades files and I wanted to know if this methodology can slow my site.
This is my structure of files:

show.blade.php file:

```
<div class="table-sections">
   ...
   @include('elements/table',['name' => 'table1','blocks' => $blocks1])
   ...
   @include('elements/table',['name' => 'table2','blocks' => $blocks2])
   ...
</div>
```

table.blade.php file:

```
...
@foreach($blocks as $block)
   ...
   @foreach($block['sections'] as $section)
      ...
      @foreach($section['rows'] as $row)
          ...
          @include('elements/row','row' => $row)
          ...
      @endforeach
      ...
   @endforeach
   ...
@endforeach
...
```

row.blade.php file :

```
...
@foreach($row['attributes'] as $attribute)
   ...
   // Making the '<td>' elements with their respective attributes and html
   ...
@endforeach
...
```

I have a lot of nested 'foreach' block control sections, so I wanted to know if in this cases is better to not use the blades (for instance for the row.blade.php file)

What do you suggest?

Comment: It will slow down your site more than not using it would. This is the tradeoff you accept by abstracting anything. However, Laravel does cache the rendered views (app/storage/view/) in an effort to mitigate this.

Comment: ok, thanks. But how laravel works with the two includes in the show.blade.php file ? It includes the tables simultaneously (asynchronously) or separately

Comment: there won't be any "significant" performance difference in my opinion unless you are getting millions of hits. but, i'll advice this. abstraction is good. but don't overuse it so much that down the line, it becomes hard for you to debug months later due to layers and layers of abstraction. in your case, i don't see any need of the deepest include file.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Note: remember that blade template is based on php, just designed to make it easier, simpler and readable for developers, and it is the same as you write 3 nested for loop php. Php in general is not the fastest web language. Some times if your database server is not the same as your host server and has more performance I will use stored procedures and win some performance. Last thing it all depends how many raw it should return, if it is only few results it will be ok, but if you have a lot of page request and a lot raw at the same time, that might compromise your performance.

Comment: Try consolidating all of your for-loop code into one loop.

Answer (score 5):

Too much nesting, is really a bad practice in Laravel.
we try to make our code clean, but that causes sometimes a performance tradeoff.
thats why i ended up deciding to create  a small library that flattens the blade on production, which improves the performance up to x10 times.

try it from here:
https://packagist.org/packages/te-cho/compile-blades

basically, all it does is that it takes the blade file and it puts the includes and yields in one blade file without no includes nor yielding.

Comment: When not using includes website has initial load time of 0.8s, When I use includes it's 3s, none of the packages works, I need help. It doesnt even install:

laravel version `5.5.48`

`Problem 1
    - Installation request for te-cho/compile-blades ^1.0 -> satisfiable by te-cho/compile-blades[v1.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
`

and about 50x of these lines:
`- don't install illuminate/view v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
`

Project I joined is not small, without includes code looks crappy, I really need this package to work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#introduction)

> all Blade views are compiled into plain PHP code and cached until they are modified, meaning Blade adds essentially zero overhead to your application

I suppose if you don't tamper with your cache config, the above statement puts it straight forward.

In other words, don't be scared to take full advantage of blade templating engine.

Comment: Blade itself, yes, but if you look at a compiled view, you will see that it still has includes (if you've used `@include()`) which can be slow if too nested. It doesn't flatten the file which would be most ideal.